# Not able to load images from static folder of Django even after proper configuration

Tags: django

HTML Page:

```
 <body>
      {% load static %}
  <section class="hero is-success is-fullheight">
    <div class="hero-body">
      <div class="container has-text-centered">
        <div class="column is-4 is-offset-4">
          <h3 class="title has-text-grey">Login</h3>
          <div class="box">
            <figure class="avatar">
              <img src="{% static 'images/abc.png' %}">
            </figure>
```

Settings.py configuration

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
STATIC_ROOT = '/staticfiles/'
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

When i try to load an image using the above configuration. I am unable to get the response. Error is throwing like

```
"GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/abc.png 404 (Not Found)"
```

[image: Attached the image of my django architecture. Please help me resolve this issue.]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add project name in installed_apps

When i added it worked !